# Call method from another class with out parameter using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, out

In my backgroundworker, it need to call methods from another class come with out parameter.

**[Class 1]**

```
    public partial Class1 : Form
    {
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView gv;
            int param1, param2;

            Class2 class2 = new Class2();
            class2.method(gv, out param1, out param2);
        }
    }
```

**[Class 2]**

```
    public Class2
    {
        public void method(DataGridView gv, out int param1, out int param2)
        {
            param1 = 0;
            param2 = 0;

            // basically grab the data in dataGridView and load into database
        }
    }
```

How should i correctly call `Class2.method` without the error `Cross-thread operation not valid: 'class2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created`?

Comment: Is Class2 a Windows Forms control?

Comment: no, Class2 is just a normal class

Comment: Definitely need more information about this.  Can you post Class2 code, and what are param2 and param3, and what does method do?  There's no intrinsic reason that an out parameter would cause any issue running on a different thread.  The code you have there as-is should work fine, assuming nothing is interacting with any Form or user control.

Comment: How are you invoking your background worker, and how does the `out` parameter come in to play? I'm wondering if it's a problem with the `out` parameter and crossing threads.  Have you tried it without the `out` parameter to see if you have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, i have tried without the `out` parameter, but i still get the same error.

Comment: There's still something missing.  Passing in a DataView should be fine and not cause issues.  The code as-is is still fine.  I just scaffolded up your code and ran it, and it ran ok.

Comment: But that's all for my code, if i did not call class2.method, everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the class2.method() call, and tried to step into the function?  Does it immediately throw the exception before getting to the param2 = 0 line?  Is there a variable called class2 declared somewhere else in Class1?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, its a dataGridView not a dataView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit/modify Forms or user controls on threads on which they were not created.  In order to do this, you'll need to extract the data you need from the DataGridView on the UI thread, and put that into a data structure (like a DataTable for example) that isn't a control or form (or pass it in to the background worker as an argument).  Then retrieve your data from that data structure in your background thread, and add it to the DB.